# Setting compiler flags per file in projct template file TemplateInfo.plist

Tags: xcode4, automatic-ref-counting, project-template, compiler-flags

I created a project template file - TemplateInfo.plist which is defined with ARC usage.
There are a few external files which I included in the template that are not ARC supported. In a regular project I would set manually the compiler flags for those files in build phases-> compile sources to -fno-objc-arc but how can I do it inside the template?
I didn't find anything related.. any idea?

Thanks